# Agregar fila a una tabla html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estaba practicando algo simple en jquery, en este caso agregar nuevas filas a una tabla a través de un botón, para lo cual tengo dos fragmentos de código:

El primero usando el selector `tbody:last-child` y la funcion `append()` de jquery.

```js
$("#add").on("click", function(){
  $('#test > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>'+$("#nombre").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#apellido").val()+'</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test Tabla</title>
</head>
<body>
  Nombre: <input type="text" id="nombre">
  Apellido: <input type="text" id="apellido">
  <button type="button" id="add">Agregar</button>
<table id="test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Luis
      </td>
      <td>
        Paredes
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Y el segundo usando el selector `tr:last` y la función `after()`

```js
$("#add").on("click", function(){
  $('#test tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+$("#nombre").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#apellido").val()+'</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  Nombre: <input type="text" id="nombre">
  Apellido: <input type="text" id="apellido">
  <button type="button" id="add">Agregar</button>
<table id="test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Luis
      </td>
      <td>
        Paredes
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo, y cual de las dos formas esta mejor implementada?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sí, existen muchas otras formas de hacerlo, la verdad y con todo respeto creo que tantas como podamos imaginar y crear. En SO en inglés hay una [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery) que ofrece más de 20 opciones distintas para hacer esto.

---

¿Cuál de las dos está mejor implementada? Creo que no hay mayor diferencia, simplemente son dos formas distintas de solucionar el problema.

En términos de código fuente de los métodos empleados, la diferencia entre uno y otro debería ser mínima en términos de rendimiento:

```
append: function() {
    return domManip( this, arguments, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
            var target = manipulationTarget( this, elem );
            target.appendChild( elem );
        }
    } );
},


after: function() {
    return domManip( this, arguments, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.parentNode ) {
            this.parentNode.insertBefore( elem, this.nextSibling );
        }
    } );
},
```

Por último, en cuanto a la implementación que haces, se podrían mejorar levemente los selectores, en el primer caso no es necesario especificar `:last-child` y en el segundo podríamos evitar el uso del selector descendiente y agregar `tbody`, en caso que haya `<tfoot>` al final de la tabla.

```js
$("#add").on("click", function(){
  $('#test > tbody').append('<tr><td>'+$("#nombre").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#apellido").val()+'</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test Tabla</title>
</head>
<body>
  Nombre: <input type="text" id="nombre">
  Apellido: <input type="text" id="apellido">
  <button type="button" id="add">Agregar</button>
<table id="test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Luis
      </td>
      <td>
        Paredes
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$("#add").on("click", function(){
  $('#test > tbody > tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+$("#nombre").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#apellido").val()+'</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  Nombre: <input type="text" id="nombre">
  Apellido: <input type="text" id="apellido">
  <button type="button" id="add">Agregar</button>
<table id="test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Luis
      </td>
      <td>
        Paredes
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, si revise esa pregunta, lo que me hizo pensar es que fue formulada en 2008 y puede ser que ahora existan algunas formas adicionales de hacerlo. Gracias me sirvió tu respuesta :)

Answer (score 2):

Añadiendo a la excelente respuesta de @Shaz:

> ¿Cuál de las dos está mejor implementada?

Si te refieres a implementación en términos generales, ninguna. Evita usar ese tipo de código no-reusable, en su lugar puedes usar funciones para ello que sirvan como plantillas. Por ejemplo, tu código se puede modularizar así:

```js
function addPerson(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const row = createRow({
    name: $('#name').val(),
    lastname: $('#lastname').val()
  });
  $('table tbody').append(row);
  clean();
}

function createRow(data) {
  return (
    `<tr>` +
      `<td>${$('tbody tr').length + 1}</td>` +
      `<td>${data.name}</td>` +
      `<td>${data.lastname}</td>` +
    `</tr>`
  );
}

function clean() {
  $('#name').val('');
  $('#lastname').val('');
  $('#name').focus();
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  display: inline-flex;
}
form input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  padding: .4rem .8rem;
}
form button {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  border: 1px solid #1abc9c;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.93);
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: .4rem 1rem;
  transition: background-color .2s ease,
    color .2s ease;
}
form button:hover {
  background-color: #ffF;
  color: #1abc9c;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
table thead th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-weight: 500;
}
table thead th,
table tbody td {
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: .5rem .65rem;
}
table thead th:not(:last-of-type),
table tbody td:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table thead tr,
table tbody tr:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form onsubmit="addPerson(event)">
    <section class="group">
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Nombre" />
      <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Apellido" />
    </section>
    <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
  </form>
  
  <table style="display: inline-block">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Sobre rendimiento entre `jQuery#append` y `jQuery#after`, no hay diferencias notables.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, tienes razón, es mejor hacer código reusable :)